# Wordpress add redirect to 404

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress, redirect

could here someone know please?
Wordpress redirected to similar parent page if this exists, I need to add redirect to 404

For example I’ve created page
Website.com/parent1/child2
If I put
Website.com/parent2/child2
It’s redirected me to
Website.com/parent1/child2

So I need to 404 page, any ideas?

I’m also try use plugins

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code to redirect specific page url to 404 page.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_404_to_homepage' );

function redirect_404_to_homepage(){
   if(is_404()):
        wp_safe_redirect( home_url('/') );
        exit;
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://example.com/404-page");
exit();
?>
```

In this example, the code uses the header() function to send a 301 "Moved Permanently" HTTP status code and a new location header to redirect the user to the http://example.com/404-page URL.

Note that this code should be placed at the top of your 404.php template, before any other HTML or PHP code. You should replace http://example.com/404-page with the URL of the custom 404 page you want to redirect to.

Comment: They don't want to redirect their 404 page somewhere else. The want to _trigger_ the 404 error for requests to pages that don't exist, instead of having WP redirect to a similar named alternative.